# Добавление в БД mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно одним запросом добавить 4 пустых записи в БД. Этот код добавляет одну. А как сделать, чтобы 4?

```
$add_shablon = $row_shablon['shablon'];
            $query = "INSERT INTO products (alias,parent,shablon) VALUES 
            ('','','')";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Comment: В вопросах SQL я слабоват, но почему бы не вывести через for()?

Comment: зачем мне выводить? мне добавить надо

Comment: Я слово "вывести" использовал не в том смысле =)

Comment: уже это сделал

Comment: @LLIAKAJI Лайк, это одно, но есть ещё чуть ниже "галка" (серая в кружочке). Жмакаем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO products (alias,parent,shablon) VALUES('','',''),('','',''),('','',''),('','','');
```

Comment: вот это то что надо